# Fill a column at missing year/quarter with 0 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. `value` is missing for some `year_Quarter`.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'Year_Quarter':['2017_Q1', '2017_Q3', '2017_Q4',
                             '2018_Q1', '2018_Q2', '2018_Q4'],
              'Value': [12, 14, 2, 44, 5, 33]})

Year_Quarter Value
0   2017_Q1   12
1   2017_Q3   14
2   2017_Q4   2
3   2018_Q1   44
4   2018_Q2   5
5   2018_Q4   33
```

what I need is a dataframe that has those missing `Year_Quarter` filled with 0, like below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Year_Quarter':['2017_Q1', '2017_Q2','2017_Q3', '2017_Q4',
                             '2018_Q1', '2018_Q2', '2018_Q3','2018_Q4'],
              'Value': [12, 0,14, 2, 44, 5, 0, 33]})


Year_Quarter Value
0   2017_Q1   12
1   2017_Q2   0
2   2017_Q3   14
3   2017_Q4   2
4   2018_Q1   44
5   2018_Q2   5
6   2018_Q3   0
7   2018_Q4   33
```

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a second dataframe with all the needed ```Year_Quarter`` values
like this

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Year_Quarter':['2017_Q1', '2017_Q2','2017_Q3', '2017_Q4',
                             '2018_Q1', '2018_Q2', '2018_Q3','2018_Q4']})
```

Then merge the two data frames and fill `NaN` values with zero

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Comment: This is not very general. What if OP has 500 missing values?

Answer (score 3):

Munge `df` to make `Year_Quarter` into periods

```
df = df.assign(
    Year_Quarter=
    df.Year_Quarter.map(lambda x: pd.Period(x.replace('_', ''), 'Q'))
).set_index('Year_Quarter')
```

Create an index that is a range of periods

```
idx = pd.period_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='Q', name=df.index.name)
```

Then use `reindex`

```
df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

              Value
Year_Quarter       
2017Q1           12
2017Q2            0
2017Q3           14
2017Q4            2
2018Q1           44
2018Q2            5
2018Q3            0
2018Q4           33
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get the quarterly data in stock earnings format such as : "2020-06-30 , 2020-03-30" instead of the "2020Q1" format?